# echo the output of a ls command with less files than n

Tags: linux, bash

I have 400 folders with several files inside, I am interested in:

1. counting how many files with the extension `.solution` are in each folder, and
2. then output only those folder have less than 440 elements

The point 1) is easy to get with the command:

```
for folder in $(ls -d */ | grep "sol_cv_");
do
    a=$(ls -1 "$folder"/*.solution | wc -l); 
    echo $folder has "${a}" files;
done
```

But is there any easy way to filter only the files with less than 440 elements?

Comment: The folder immediately above the file?

Comment: Yes, there are no subfolders, each folder has a bunch of txt files but I only am interested in those with `*.solution` extension

Comment: @user2380782 : Could you update the question with the base folder for `400 folders`

Comment: my base folder is /home/jfertaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple script could work for you:-

```
 #!/bin/bash

 MAX=440

 for folder in sol_cv_*; do
     COUNT=$(find "$folder" -type f -name "*.solution" | wc -l)
     ((COUNT < MAX)) && echo "$folder"
 done
```

Answer (score 1):

The script below

```
counterfun(){
count=$(find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.solution" | wc -l)
(( count < 440 )) && echo "$1"
}
export -f counterfun
find /YOUR/BASE/FOLDER/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname "sol_cv_*" -exec bash -c 'counterfun "$1"' _ {} \;
#maxdepth 1 in both find above as you've confirmed no sub-folders
```

should do it

Answer (score 1):

Avoid parsing `ls` command and use `printf '%q\n` for counting files:

```
for folder in *sol_cv_*/; do
    # if there are less than 440 elements then skip
    (( $(printf '%q\n' "$folder"/* | wc -l) < 440 )) && continue
    # otherwise print the count using safer printf '%q\n'
    echo "$folder has $(printf '%q\n' "$folder"*.solution | wc -l) files"
done
```

Comment: your command doesn't give me an output, and at least there are 10 folders with less than 440 `*.solution` files

Comment: this is an example of the ouput: `sol_cv_212/:2
sol_cv_213/:2
sol_cv_214/:2
sol_cv_215/:2
sol_cv_216/:2
sol_cv_217/:2`

Comment: thanks @anubhava, but now we are missing the listing of files with less elements than 440...

Comment: Ah yes, it is added back now. Try it now.

Comment: Sorry, I was busy doing other things. it is still not working, it outputs all the files not filtering by number

Comment: That is possible only if `*.solution` files are in further deep sub-directories.